# spark: apply explode to a list of columns in a dataFrame, but not to all columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a list of column names 
`val expFields = List("f1", "f2")` and a dataFrame df, and I'd like to explode columns in the expField list of df. That means I'd like to apply "explode" to a select number of columns and return a new dataFrame. I don't want to manually specify column names like `df.withColumn("f1", explode(col("f1"))).withColumn("f2", explode(col("f2")))`. I'd like to use the expFields list to specify these columns. How do I do that in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fold over the list of columns:

```
expFields.foldLeft(df)((acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, explode(col(c))))
```